# Create a multiple ring buffer according to field value + fixed set of values (ArcPy, Python)

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I'm trying to find a code that will get the values from a
specific columm (width) of a lines feature dataset and sum it with a fixed set of values (10, 20 and 30 meters) in order to apply a Multiple Ring Buffer.

Attribute table:
[image]

The code sample below uses the fixed set of values (10, 20 and 30 meters) but not the width values of my lines shapefile.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/Py.gdb"
outFeatureClass = "c:/output/multibuffer"
distances = [10,20,30]
bufferUnit = "meters"
Field_Name = ""
dissolveType = "ALL"
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis("lines", outFeatureClass, distances, bufferUnit, Field_Name, dissolveType)
```

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of the attribute table

Comment: Just run the Merge tool to combine the outputs? As your loop is creating output names store that in a list and pass that into a Merge tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Hornbydd mentions in comments, merging all feature class will do it for you.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/Py.gdb"
fc = "lines"
distances = [10,20,30]

#empty list for feature classes
fcs = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@', 'width','OID@']) as cursor:
    for geom, width, oid in cursor:
        arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(Input_Features=geom,
                                         Output_Feature_class='Multibuffer_{0}'.format(oid),
                                         Distances=[i+width for i in distances],
                                         Buffer_Unit='meters',
                                         Dissolve_Option='ALL')
        #add buffer to feature class list
        fcs += ['Multibuffer_{0}'.format(oid)]

#merge feature classes
arcpy.Merge_management (fcs, "Multibuffers")

#clean up
for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.Delete_management (fc)
```

If you want to go faster, create a new feature class, create your buffers in memory, and insert the geometries as you go.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/Py.gdb"
fc = "lines"
distances = [10,20,30]

#fc spatial refernce
sr = arcpy.Describe (fc).spatialReference
#create feature class
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management ("C:/data/Py.gdb", "Multibuffers", "POLYGON", spatial_reference = sr)
#insert cursor to insert geometries into feature class
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor ("Multibuffers", ["SHAPE@"]) as iCurs:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@', 'width','OID@']) as cursor:
        for geom, width, oid in cursor:
            #buffer in memory
            arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(Input_Features=geom,
                                             Output_Feature_class=r'in_memory\buffs',
                                             Distances=[i+width for i in distances],
                                             Buffer_Unit='meters')

            #iterate buffers and add to output feature class
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (r'in_memory\buffs', ["SHAPE@"]) as sCurs:
                for row in sCurs:
                    iCurs.insertRow (row)

            #delete in memory buffers
            arcpy.Delete_management (r'in_memory\buffs')
```

Comment: Thank you Emil, I am gonna go for the second solution since my real dataset is made of hundred of thousands of roads. I hope it will not saturate the memory but I guess the buffers are stored in the memory the same way when you launch a standard buffer from the toolbox.

Comment: With my code only one multi ring buffer is stored in memory at a time.